# I am getting error using streamlit library

Tags: openai-api, streamlit, langchain

I am trying to create basic langchain model using langchain, openAI and Streamlit libraies, however getting error while executing the code.

```
(deploy) C:\Users\Rimpy\Desktop\deployment\Langchain_detect_celebrity_face>streamlit run main.py

C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.XWYDX2IKJW2NMTWSFYNGFUWKQU3LYTCZ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\streamlit\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from streamlit.delta_generator import DeltaGenerator as _DeltaGenerator
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\streamlit\delta_generator.py", line 42, in <module>
    from streamlit.elements.arrow import ArrowMixin
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\arrow.py", line 23, in <module>
    from streamlit.elements.lib.column_config_utils import (
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\lib\column_config_utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from streamlit.elements.lib.column_types import ColumnConfig, ColumnType
  File "C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\lib\column_types.py", line 20, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Literal, NotRequired, TypeAlias, TypedDict
ImportError: cannot import name 'NotRequired' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Users\Rimpy\anaconda3\envs\deploy\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

`
I want to see the website page, here is the full code :

### Integrate the code opeanAI API

`

```
import os
 from constant import openai_key

 from langchain.llms import OpenAI

 import streamlit as st

 os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEYS'] = openai_key

 # streamlit framework
 st.title('Langchain Demo with OpenAI API')
 input_text = st.text_input('Seach the topic you want')

 ## OPENAI LLMs

 llm = OpenAI(temperature = 0.8)

 if input_text:
       st.write(llm(input_text))
```